# what after only touches Began?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

In my iPad app...

I am doing some stuff of dragging an object....

My problem is for dragging I need two methods...

1. touches began `some stuff1`
2. touches moved  `some stuff2`

**Sometimes what happens that the user is not moving  the object after touching.**
So, whateever `somestuff1` has been done.
I need to reverse it back..

So,How would I do that...

[image]

Means is there any event or notification that I can fire

if the user does the touches began and not touches ended.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will always receive a `touchesEnded:withEvent:` message or a `touchesCancelled:withEvent:` message after you have received a `touchesBegan:withEvent:` message.  You need to override both methods if you want to know when the user has lifted his finger.

If you want to track whether the user moved the touch before lifting his finger, you have to do that yourself.  You can set a flag in your `touchesMoved:withEvent:` method, or you can save the original position of the touch in `touchesBegin:withEvent:` and then compare it with the final position of the touch in `touchesEnded:withEvent:` and `touchesCancelled:withEvent:`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a `- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` function, too, use it to check if the user hasn't made any moves.